# How do you call an install function that did not run during install?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, hooks, installation

I am using the [Currency Taxonomy](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency_taxonomy) module to get all valid currencies around the globe as taxonomy terms. On installing the module, I got the taxonomy vocabulary but not the terms.

The code to add the terms is in the [install hook](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/currency_taxonomy/-/blob/8.x-1.4/currency_taxonomy.install) but did not get executed for some reason.  Reinstalling the module helped.

However, I need to export this 'reinstall' which I am not able to figure out how to do. I am thinking of calling the adding taxonomy terms function from another module in a hook update.

Does anyone have better solution than this?

Comment: I think the install hook doesn't get triggered when the module gets installed from configuration import. Can't you simply uninstall and reinstall it? Or you could copy the code from the install hook into your own custom module's hook_update_N. And you should also raise an issue about this problem in the module's issue queue.

Comment: I think it was a problem with my site. Others were not having a problem. However there were no errors in my log. Strangely the config import of my config export in another site also resulted in the same missing taxonomy terms.

Comment: Terms are content, not config. But some months ago I experienced a similar problem when trying to create dummy content upon module installation. This worked when enabled manually, but it didn't work when the module got enabled upon configuration import.

Comment: You are right. However the module has all the currencies in the code itself, which is added during hook_install. See here. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/currency_taxonomy/-/blob/8.x-1.x/currency_taxonomy.module. Not sure why It was no added for me. Also in the staging server the terms were not populated even though moduled was enaled from configuration.

Comment: When you checked your logs did you check your php/apache logs too? As sometimes I've had an error occur within a hook_install and the module gets enabled but no error is shown on screen/watchdog (I'm guessing depending when the error happened) In those situations I've just manually called the install function within code e.g. `currency_taxonomy_install();`

Comment: @Binny – Try to reproduce it in a Vanilla Drupal. Drush site install standard profile, Drush enable Currency Taxonomy. Terms should be there. Now export config and temp store site UUID somewhere. Drop database, reinstall Drupal, Drush set site UUID, import config, Currency Taxonomy should be installed but terms not there. Because the module got installed from config and this somehow skips hook_install or certain function calls in it.

Comment: hook_install() is only executed on install. If it's added after the module has been installed, it will not be executed. In such a case, you'll need to create a hook_update_N() implementation to run the code.

Comment: @Jaypan – This is not OP's problem. I've described it here in more detail: https://www.drupal.org/project/currency_taxonomy/issues/3133817

Comment: Thanks @leymannx. I guess its the config import is the problem. Not sure why hook install is not being executed on config import.